# Trazer dados do BD com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, banco-de-dados

Olá ! Eu tenho um MENU e um submenu dentro de cada item deste menu.

Toda vez que eu clico em um item do menu, ele abre um sub-menu (efeito sanfona).
Há uma maneira de fazer um `select` dentro da base de dados e trabalhar com o resultado destes select, dentro do JS ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({});
});

    $('#addEvent').click(function() {  

      //BUSCAR OS DADOS DO BANCO AQUI, PARA USA-LOS ALI EMBAIXO.
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
        'renderEvent',
        {
          title: 'Novo evento', // <-- Inserir os dados aqui
          start: '2016-03-31',  // <-- Inserir os dados aqui também
        }
      );
    });
```

Obs: Não achei nada, mas vale citar. Estou utilizando `laravel`, eu não achei nada, mas talvez ele tenha algo que ajude nisso...
Obs2: Não é obrigatório ser `javascript`, mas não vejo como usar `php` para inserir os dados neste bloco.

Comment: Você precisa de uma linguagem de programação, php por exemplo, mas se quiser fazer somente em javascript você pode usar node.js como o cara citou agora.

Comment: Mas tem como usar o PHP pra puxar os dados na hora que clico no menu ? Pois eu precisaria add os dados no evento que mostrei no código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quiser usar somente Java Script, recomendo o uso de Node.js. É uma plataforma construída sobre o motor JavaScript, você pode fazer uma aplicação completa com back end usando somente Java Script.

Referência:https://nodejs.org

Comment: E seria possível usar php para inserir os dados naquele bloco de código que eu mostrei ? como ? Falei em JS, pois achei que não seria possível usar o php ali.

Comment: Sim claro mas você primeiro precisa criar seu arquivo PHP que faz a consulta no banco, um método php que retorna os dados que você quer.E depois via javascript fazer uma requisição ajax, que vai no php e tras os dados pra o javascript.

Comment: Como estou utilizando laravel, além de dizer o arquivo php da consulta, tem como especificar um método lá dentro? (Controller). Ou devo criar um arquivo a parte, só pra isso ?

Comment: o certo é criar os controllers separados da consulta ao banco, usar o padrão MVC que o laravel oferece.Acho que você deve entender melhor o conceito de serviço, ultilizar um RESTful pra fazer a requisição ajax do javascript, pra o seu php. Estude MVC com laravel, veja essa aula: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdZ956XwoFY